# Algorithm: separate a list of values into subsets by minimizing the maximal difference in the sums of elements between all sublists

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, computation-theory

I have a list of values (integers) that I would like to split into *B*  non-empty sublists without changing their initial order. The goal is to adjust the size of text to fit it into a defined area.

Each sublist will have one metric associated to it : the sum of its values. I would like to minimise the **difference *DIFF*** between the **biggest sum and smallest sum among all the sublists**. This would allow me to **divide text into lines with approximately the same amount of text**.

**EDIT**

As suggested, it would also work to minimise the maximal sum, as that would result in minimising the maximal length of a line of text.

**Examples:**

Given the list L = {2,3,4,5,6} and B = 2.

Solution : L1 = {2,3,4} and L2 = {5,6}. Sum(L1) = 9, Sum(L2) = 11 and DIFF = 2

---

Given the List L = {1,1,8,1,1,1,8,1} and B = 3

Solution : L1 = {1,1,8}, L2 = {1,1,1} and L3 = {8,1}.Sum(L1) = 10, Sum(L2) = 3, Sum(L3) = 9 and DIFF = 7

**My suggestion**

As I don't have an IT background, I'm not sure how to approach this.
First, I tried to figure out the number of combinations I could split my original set into ***B* sublists**. The **number of elements in the original list** is **N**, then there would be a number of possible splits equal to:

[image: equation]

Then I tried to see what would be an appropriate algorithm to find the global minimum. I thought that if I ran into a situation where both of the conditions below are respected, I would have hit the global minimum.

- Moving an element from (one of) the biggest sublist(s) into (one of) its neighbour(s) doesn't improve *DIFF*.
- Moving an element from the (one of) the smallest sublist(s) into (one of) its neighbour(s) doesn't improve *DIFF*.

(As the sublists must not be empty, moving an element from a sublist with only one element requires to change several sublists)

**Questions**

Are the two conditions mentioned sufficient to guarantee a global minimum (for DIFF) ?

Do you know / remember an algorithm solving this problem ? Or do you have a suggestion to solve this ?

Do you have any reading recommendations to help me to tackle this kind of problem ?

As I said, I don't have an It background and don't have much experience with such computer theory problems.

Thank you !

Comment: Do you need an algorithm to always find the exact best possible solution?  Or is a heuristic that finds solutions close to the optimal acceptable?

Comment: Hey. Thank you for the response. Set are indeed lists, because the position of the element must be taken into account  while moving the element from a sublist into another.

Comment: Correcting my earlier comment:  "*the sum of its elements*" in your description is not a *parameter* of a sublist, rather it is a *metric* of it.

Comment: It might have been simpler to just talk in plain English about the real problem "The goal is to adjust the size of text to fit it into a defined area." We all have an intuitive understanding that words should retain their order and be split only between words, not in-between words

Comment: Finally, are you sure you really want to minimize the difference between the biggest and smallest sum? Another option would be to simply minimize the biggest sum

Comment: Hey Aaron. Minimising the maximal sum would indeed also be fine for this particular situation. Would that make the problem easier ?

Comment: Interesting problem!  I thought there'd be an easy DP, but if there is I don't see it.  I eventually thought of a more complicated DP with (possibly loose) running time bound O(BN^4 log N), which I'll try to describe when I get time.  It critically depends on a dominance rule that can discard certain solutions to subproblems.

Comment: For the time being, a couple of quick points: (1) If a solution with DIFF=0 exists, then it must consist of exactly B blocks each having sum exactly T/B, where T is the sum of all numbers.  You can easily check for this in linear time by greedily building blocks of exactly this size.  (In fact, if T/B is not an integer then you can rule out the possibility right away!)  (2) If a solution with DIFF=1 exists, then it must consist of blocks of 2 different weights, X and X+1.  ...

Comment: ... Suppose there are p weight-X blocks and q weight-(X+1) blocks: we know p+q=B, p >= 1 and q >= 1, and also that pX+q(X+1) = T.  The smallest possible value of pX+q(X+1) occurs when p=1 and q=B-1, i.e. when it is X+(B-1)(X+1) = B(X+1)-1.  Thus if X is chosen so that B(X-1)-1 > T, then there is no way to choose p and q to satisfy pX+q(X+1) = T.  IOW, we get an upper bound on X: B(X-1)-1 <= T, implying X <= (T+1)/B+1.  Also we get a lower bound by noticing that the largest possible value of pX+q(X+1) occurs when p=B-1 and q=1, i.e. when it is (B-1)X+X+1 = BX+1.  Thus if X is chosen so that ...

Comment: ... BX+1 < T, then there is no way to choose p and q to satisfy pX+q(X+1) = T.  That is, we have that BX+1 >= T, which rearranges to X >= (T-1)/B.  So, it suffices to try breaking the list into blocks of either X or X+1 for all values of X between (T-1)/B and (T+1)/B+1, inclusive.  During this search, you only need to backtrack and consider both possibilities (X and X+1) for the current block if it so happens that it forms an X-block *and* the next number is 1 -- something that should happen rarely.  Otherwise (and in particular, if there are no 1s), the same greedy algorithm works!  :)

Comment: @ j_random_hacker I don't get this explanation. X is what I'm actually looking for. As suggested by Aaron McDaid, one could choose to minimise it. But how do you search X ?

Answer (score 2):

**Q: Are the two conditions mentioned sufficient to guarantee a global minimum (for DIFF) ?**

**A: NO**

consider the following list:  `{6,5,2,4,3,7}  with B=3`

and the following potential solution:

```
{6} {5,2,4} {3,7};  Sums=(6,11,10),  DIFF = 11-6 = 5
```

All one-element changes from the largest group make DIFF worse, or leave it the same:

```
{6,5} {2,4} {3,7};  Sums=(6,11,10),  DIFF = 11-6 = 5
{6} {5,2} {4,3,7};  Sums=(6,7,14),  DIFF = 14-6 = 8
{6} {5,2,4,3} {7};  Sums=(6,14,7),  DIFF = 14-6 = 8
```

But there *is* a better solution:

```
{6,5} {2,4,3} {7};  Sums=(11,9,7),  DIFF = 11-7 = 5
```

So your method only finds local minima, not global ones.

Comment: Thank you for the example given. But as I understand, your example shows that global optimal may not be unique (several splits may lead to the same metric). It does not provider a better solution ?

Comment: @Gordak oops, right.  I will see if I can provide a corrected counter-example ...

Comment: @Gordak OK, I beleieve I have a corrected counter-solution posted.

Comment: Okay, So the two conditions are not sufficient. There is just a small change to bring to the last part: DIFF = 11-4 = 5 (to be DIFF = 11-7 = 4.
Thank you for taking the time to find a good counter-example.

Comment: @Gordak OK, fixed now.